# Weird CSS overflow issue

Tags: html, css, sass, overflow, responsive

I am experiencing a bug on my website when viewed by a mobile device. My `aside` has a `ul` in it's contents. On mobile, this `aside` sort of becomes smaller. I can add a `overflow-y` to view everything, but I just want the `aside` or the `ul` to be bigger but whatever I try, it doesn't seem to work.

**The site: 83.82.195.132**

My sass for the buggy part:

```
    {
        overflow-y: auto;
        padding: 0 20px;
        
        ul
        {
            list-style: none;
        }
        
        .channels-list-header
        {
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-top: 20px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            color: rgba($body-color, 0.3);
            font-size: 0.87rem;
            letter-spacing: 0.04rem;
            transition: color 0.2s linear;
            line-height: 30px;
            position: relative;
            h5{
                float: left;
            }
            i{
                float: right;
            }
            &:hover, &:focus
            {
                color: $body-color;
                
                &::after
                {
                    opacity: 1;
                }
            }
            
            
        }
    }
    @media all and(max-width: 769px){
        .channels-list{
            height: 250px;
        }
    }
```

My HTML code for the buggy part:

```
<section class="channels-list">
            <header class="channels-list-header focusable">
                <h5>Text Channels</h5><i onclick="test()" id="new" class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            </header>
            
            <ul class="channels-list-text" id="texts">
                <li class="channel focusable channel-text active">
                    <a><span class="channel-name">general</span></a>
                    <button class="button" aria-label="Invite"><svg><use xlink:href="#icon-invite" /></svg></button>
                    <button class="button" aria-label="settings"><svg><use xlink:href="#icon-channel-settings" /></svg></button>
                </li>
                
                <li class="channel focusable channel-text">
                <a href="/dashboard"><span class="channel-name">projects</span></a>
                    <button class="button" aria-label="Invite"><svg><use xlink:href="#icon-invite" /></svg></button>
                    <button class="button" aria-label="settings"><svg><use xlink:href="#icon-channel-settings" /></svg></button>
                </li>
                <li class="channel focusable channel-text ">
                <a href="/about"><span class="channel-name">about</span></a>
                    <button class="button" aria-label="Invite"><svg><use xlink:href="#icon-invite" /></svg></button>
                    <button class="button" aria-label="settings"><svg><use xlink:href="#icon-channel-settings" /></svg></button>
                </li>
                <li class="channel focusable channel-text ">
                <a href="/contact"><span class="channel-name">contact</span></a>
                    <button class="button" aria-label="Invite"><svg><use xlink:href="#icon-invite" /></svg></button>
                    <button class="button" aria-label="settings"><svg><use xlink:href="#icon-channel-settings" /></svg></button>
                </li>
            </ul>
</aside>
```

I really hope someone can either enlighten me about where te problem might be, or helping me to fix this.

Cheers!
Divani

Comment: Is it the height, set at a fixed 250px for narrower viewports, or the size of the font that you wish could be bigger?

Comment: i got it working already the lazy way. just reduced the font size and reduced more padding so it fits haha. Anyways, thanks for your solution. When this happens to me again I'll try your solution out